# What is the C# equivalent for PHP serialize

Tags: c#, php, serialization

I have some code in PHp, which I am trying to redo in C#. The PHP code has something like fputs($file,serialize($val))

What could be the dot NET specifically C# equivalent of Serialize???

Comment: Remember that your type and all of it's properties should be augmented by Serializable Attrbite

Answer (score 4):

```
using (Stream stream = File.Open(filePath, FileMode.Create))
{
    BinaryFormatter bformatter = new BinaryFormatter();
    bformatter.Serialize(stream, myObject);
}
```

Comment: I used BinaryFormatter but the formatted output is not the same as PHP output. Is both the functions  formats to a stream of byte then why is the output different??

Comment: @xaria: Why should it be the same? A Russian and English translation of the same book do not produce the same output...

Comment: I think @xaria wants to produce the same output as PHP serialize() from .NET code.

Answer (score 3):

As with most things in .NET, there's many ways to get there depending on how you're planning to use it.

Ways I can think of in the .NET BCL:

- XmlSerializer as pointed out by Zach
- BinaryFormatter as RedFilter points out,
- WCF's DataContract XML/JSON Serializer

I like the WCF DataContract Serializer generally because I can choose either XML or JSON as needed, and I don't need to mark up my classes (.NET 3.5 SP1+) to make basic serialization work. I wrote a few helpers for this purpose: http://will.hughesfamily.net.au/20090309/net-35-helper-methods-serialize-objects-to-xml/

Answer (score 1):

The [Sharp Serialization Library](http://csphpserial.sourceforge.net/) worked for me when porting [serialize](https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.serialize.php) calls from vBulletin to C#. But in the `serialize` method I had to replace `StringEncoding.GetByteCount(str)` by `str.Length` because `StringEncoding.GetByteCount` gave me the length + 1, which caused problems on deserialization using PHP. So the whole line should be

```
return sb.Append("s:" + str.Length + ":\"" + str + "\";");
```

Answer (score 0):

.NET provides either binary or XML/SOAP serialization. See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7ay27kt9%28VS.71%29.aspx).